# Dynamic nested object in PHP Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to nest my object depending on the `parent` value. I want to nest the array to its parent. Here's my example object:

```
    $mainObject = [
        {
            id : 1,
            title : 'title 1',
            parent: 0,
        },
        {
            id : 2,
            title : 'title 2',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id : 3,
            title : 'title 3',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id : 4,
            title : 'title 4',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id : 5,
            title : 'title 5',
            parent: 4
        },
        {
            id : 6,
            title : 'title 6',
            parent: 4
        }
    ];
```

Now, I want to produce something like this below

```
    $mainObject = [
        {
            id : 1,
            title : 'title 1',
            parent: 0,
            children: [
                {
                    id : 3,
                    title : 'title 3',
                    parent: 1
                },
                {
                    id : 4,
                    title : 'title 4',
                    parent: 1,
                    children: [
                        {
                            id : 5,
                            title : 'title 5',
                            parent: 4
                        },
                        {
                            id : 6,
                            title : 'title 6',
                            parent: 4
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id : 2,
            title : 'title 2',
            parent: 0
        },
    ];
```

My `foreach`

```
            $nested = [];

            foreach ($mainObject as $v) {
                if($v->parent == 0){
                    array_push($nested, $v);
                }
            }
```

I tried to `foreach` and group them but I couldn't figure out how can I achieve a 3-level-nest like the above. Please help me, I've been stock for 2 nights now.

Please note that the `$mainObject` is a response from my `laravel app`. You can share JS solution or vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending the 3 to 4 hours, I solved in array version. Check the solution in array version like this:

```
$mainObject = '[
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "title" : "title 1",
        "parent": "0"
    },
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "title" : "title 2",
        "parent": "0"
    },
    {
        "id" : "3",
        "title" : "title 3",
        "parent": "1"
    },
    {
        "id" : "4",
        "title" : "title 4",
        "parent": "1"
    },
    {
        "id" : "5",
        "title" : "title 5",
        "parent": "4"
    },
    {
        "id" : "6",
        "title" : "title 6",
        "parent": "4"
    }
]';

$mainArray = json_decode($mainObject, true);

function recurse_uls ($array, $parent)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $c => $p)  {
        if ($p['parent'] != $parent) continue;
        $return[] = $p;
        $data = recurse_uls ($array, $p['id']);
        if($data) {
            $length = count($return);
            $return[$length - 1]['children'] = $data;
        }
    }
    return empty($return) ? null : $return;
}

$data = recurse_uls ($mainArray, 0);
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a solution that uses [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) and doesn't use recursion:

```php
$array1 = [
        (object)[
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'title 1',
            'parent' => 0,
        ],
        (object)[
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'title 2',
            'parent' => 0
        ],
        (object)[
            'id' => 3,
            'title' => 'title 3',
            'parent' => 1
        ],
        (object)[
            'id' => 4,
            'title' => 'title 4',
            'parent' => 1
        ],
        (object)[
            'id' => 5,
            'title' => 'title 5',
            'parent' => 4
        ],
        (object)[
            'id' => 6,
            'title' => 'title 6',
            'parent' => 4
        ]
];

//PHP < 7.4
function nestArrayByParent($array){
    $collection = Illuminate\Support\Collection::wrap($array);

    //for each array element, by reference
    foreach($collection as &$obj){
        if(!property_exists($obj, 'parent') || $obj->parent == 0) //parent is 0 or doesn't have parent att.
            continue; //ignore.
        $parentKey = $collection->search(function($item) use($obj){
            return $item->id == $obj->parent;
        });
        $parent =& $collection[$parentKey]; //parent to which we must add $obj (by reference)

        if(!property_exists($parent, 'children') || !$parent->children)
            $parent->children = collect([]); //initialize children att if doesn't have it
        $parent->children->push($obj); //add $obj to its parent.
    }

    return $collection->filter(function($obj){
        //keep only items from the top level.
        return !property_exists($obj, 'parent') || $obj->parent == 0; 
    });
}

//PHP >= 7.4, with arrow functions
function nestArrayByParent_7_4($array){
    $collection = Illuminate\Support\Collection::wrap($array);

    //for each array element, by reference
    foreach($collection as &$obj){
        if(!property_exists($obj, 'parent') || $obj->parent == 0) //parent is 0 or doesn't have parent att.
            continue; //ignore.
        $parentKey = $collection->search(fn($item) => $item->id == $obj->parent);
        $parent =& $collection[$parentKey]; //parent to which we must add $obj (by reference)

        if(!property_exists($parent, 'children') || !$parent->children)
            $parent->children = collect([]); //initialize children att if doesn't have it
        $parent->children->push($obj); //add $obj to its parent.
    }

    //keep only items from the top level.
    return $collection->filter(fn($obj) => !property_exists($obj, 'parent') || $obj->parent == 0); 
}

//

dd(nestArrayByParent($array1));
```

Comment: Im having an `error 500`  `nestArrayByParent() must be of the type array` here's my initail query for my products `$mainObject = Product::all();`

Comment: Edited the answer removing the `array` type hint and using `Collection::wrap($array)` so that we ensure `$collection`is a Collection. 
Now the function may receive a Collection or an array (or, in fact, just an object) as a parameter.